# Plan before milestones

Tags: microsoft-project

I have 4 milestones in MS Project.  I want to program my tasks to they end at some of these milestones, and work backwards.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think is it possible. One solution would be to set your project to use a finish to start scheduling, then set some hard constraints (like MFO) on those milestones and on the rest of task use ALAP constraints and make sure all paths finish in one of those milestones. This way all task will be pushed as late as possible relative to the milestone dates.